# Papertrail color logging

Tags: javascript, node.js, papertrail-app

I've found on the internet that Papertrail lets you [log using ANSI colors](http://blog.papertrailapp.com/more-colorful-logging-with-ansi-color-codes).

That's a great deal for me because I have lots of logs on my node.js app and adding more color helps me to understand what's going on when there's a lot of people hitting the service.

So I read a little about [ANSI escape code for colors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#Colors) and I managed to write this on my terminal (which works alright)

```
printf \\x1b[31mHello\\n\\x1b[0m
```

Unfortunately when I try the same thing on my node.js app the output in papertrail is not what I'm looking for:

[image: papertrail screen]

My code in the node.js app is this:

```
logger.debug('\x1b[31mGET /app/config\x1b[0m');
```

*UPDATE: Since I'm using [nlogger](https://github.com/igo/nlogger) maybe I can use its color feature. However, I would like your opinion about this :-)*

Comment: https://github.com/Marak/colors.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using the following since I was already using nlogger:

```
logger.trace("SOMETHING HERE")
logger.info("SOMETHING HERE IN ANOTHER COLOR")
```

Answer (score 2):

you might want to check out [color](https://www.npmjs.org/package/colors) module

Sample code:

```
var colors = require('colors');

console.log('hello'.green); // outputs green text
console.log('i like cake and pies'.underline.red) // outputs red     underlined text
console.log('inverse the color'.inverse); // inverses the color
console.log('OMG Rainbows!'.rainbow); // rainbow (ignores spaces)
```

Comment: Awesome! Your answer would be the one I would implement if I wouldn't use nlogger in first place. Thanks :-)

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing that the output is the string literal `\x1b[31m` rather than the ANSI [escape sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#Sequence_elements). It's often hard to see which for sure which one is being output.

I don't have a Node example of outputting an escape code, but if you can get it to do that, Papertrail (and any ANSI-aware terminal) will render the color.

Answer (score 0):

This node.js code should work for Papertrail log coloring:

```
const RESET = '\u001b[0m'; 
const BRIGHT_RED_FG = '\u001b[31;1m';
console.log(BRIGHT_RED_FG + 'Bright red text' + RESET + ' Back to black');
```

I noticed that Papertrail accepts the 16 color set: 8 dark foreground/background colors and 8 bright foreground/background colors, but ignores ANSI codes of the extended 256 color set (which are supported nicely on some terminals).

You can find more ANSI codes and options here: http://www.lihaoyi.com/post/BuildyourownCommandLinewithANSIescapecodes.html